# Q&A sites like StackExchange: Should I build a rails engine or a single multi-tenant app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, architecture

I want to create several niche Q&A sites similar to StackExchange.

Which approach is best?...

**A) Rails mountable engine.** New sites would be full rails apps that would use this engine. The mountable engine would provide the *complete* Q&A site (code, visual styling, etc).

**B) Single multi-tenant app.** A single rails app where each new site would be added as a tenant. In this approach, something would be needed to customize the styles for each new site (logo, header, etc).

Which approach would you recommend?

Comment: Not that's it related but it might help you , someone built a clone of stackoverflow here - https://github.com/mateuszdw/qaror . Can take a lot of cues from there .

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go with Single app multi-tenant.

I had implemented this in an old project on http://mentii.com. This is a mentoring platform, but I guess similar challenges as Q&A apply.

Here, each community would get a version of the app whitelabled to their needs. I found the approach to be scalable as well as well as maintainable.